# How to convert given html string to normal string android?

Tags: android, html, textview

This is given string.

String a=<p><strong>Test</strong></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Test description</p>

How to convert this string to display and store in textview?

```
I used like this. But it is not working.

    TextView textView;
    textview.setText((Html.fromHtml(a).toString()));
```

This gives output like this:

```
   <p>strong>Test</strong></p><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;Test description</p>
```

How to set as proper String in textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
String normailString = Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text();
```

Comment: thanks will you please put like this. String htmlString=Html.fromHtml(a).toString()). so that it may help for some others in future. i will accept your answer after you done like this.

Comment: whether it's possible to do without using jsoup?

Comment: Actually 'Html.fromHtml(a).toString()' is working perfectly for me, i dont know what happened in your case. Make sure Imported is 'android.text.Html'.

Answer (score 0):

You must uses This Tag in your string.xml File :

```
<![CDATA[<h1><strong>YOUR HTML CODE HERE</strong></h1> ]]>
```

Or Try adding the CDATA Tag in your String Variable

Comment: i am getting from server response through json and storing in strings and converting that. how i can use that in strings.xml?

Comment: String a = "<![CDATA" + Your Html String + "]]>" ; i've not tried at RunTime but i uses Html in string.xml file like this